# Meaning of Arkady and Boris Strugatsky’s Philosophy

Tags: existentialism, eastern-philosophy, philosophy-of-culture, behaviorism

What is the cultural and ideological branch that the classic Soviet book “Roadside Picnic”, of which the movie “Stalker” and game series, comes from?
It does not seem to be Russian Cosmism, and neither that from Dostoevsky.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [The Human Reimagined: Posthumanism in Russia](https://www.bookfinder.com/search/?author=&title=&lang=en&isbn=9781618117793&new_used=*&destination=us&currency=USD&mode=basic&st=sr&ac=qr) which is discussed starting on p. 17 of [this thesis](https://studenttheses.universiteitleiden.nl/access/item%3A2603862/view), with p. 18 of the thesis bringing up a piece in the book that talks about *Roadside Picnic*.

Answer (score 2):

There are certainly Russian philosophies which have little made it to the West, for instance the [sobornost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobornost), and cosmists like Fyodorov. There's no evidence I think of direct influence.

An indisputable influence, is Stanislaw Lem, pre-eminent science fiction writer in the Soviet world, but sadly not much known now in the West.

It is at least cosmic-horror adjacent, with elements like the casually reanimated corpse of the protagonists father, and hairy mutating child. And the sheer unknowability and power of the visitors. It contains mysteries literally far beyond our scientific capacities, which is a key part of the genre.

I'd be more inclined to look to political, rather than philosophical context, in understanding the roots of Roadside Picnic. The political constraints that saw it's publication greatly delayed, forced on it an ambiguity, later magnified in the film which [has been described](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalker_(1979_film)#Themes_and_interpretations) as "an endlessly pliable allegory about human consciousness".

But fundamentally, it was a unique and visionary work, based on a simple premise. And it deserves consideration and credit above all in it's own right for exploring that in a way that speaks to things beyond itself.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I agree with the cosmic-horror adjacent, however that is only a medium and not an overarching philosophy or ideology, which is what I am trying to distill from this. In addition, Sobornost ideology is highly linked to a conservative, orthodox, slavophilic worldview, which I do not think "Roadside Picnic" is siding on. It was great input from your part, but I believe that it does not realize the full scope of my inquiry.

Comment: On Stanislaw Lem, he had several books about the incomprehensibility of alien intelligence which could have been an influence, especially Solaris (1961) and His Master's Voice (1968) which both predate Roadside Picnic which was written in 1971. Although the Strugatsky's earlier The Snail on the Slope also dealt with a fairly incomprehensible alien world in its "Forest" sections which were first published in 1966--still could have been influenced by Solaris at least.